# scrollTop. перезаписать значение

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть некий блок, который при скроле страницы зависает сверху, ему динамически добавляется класс с фиксированным положением.

```
var element = $(".top");

$(document).scroll(function(){
  if($(this).scrollTop() > element.position().top){
    element.addClass('intop');
  }else{
    element.removeClass('intop');
  }
});
```

После того как этот блок зафиксировался сверху, при кликах на якоря, контент "заезжает под него". При чем кликать на якоря можно как до так и после фиксации сверху блока. Можно ли как нибудь перехватить клик на анкор и переназначить позицию скрола, в зависимости от ситуации? И еще, как учесть то, что если анкор находится выше фиксируемого блока, а его контент ниже?

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#id1">Якорь 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#id2">Якорь 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#id3">Якорь 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="top">
      <h1>{$offer->name}</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="{some-link}">Купить</a></li>
        <li><a href="{some-link}">Гарантия</a></li>
        <li><a href="{some-link}">Доставка</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="id1">
      {some-content}
    </div>

    <div id="id2">
      {some-content}
    </div>

    <div id="id3">
      {some-content}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а хтмл запилить трудно было?

Comment: @Jean-Claude это как? каждому блоку с id добавить верхний отступ?

Comment: сюда добавить хтмл в реализацией вашей проблемы.

Comment: @Jean-Claude ну вот примерно вот так...

Answer (score 1):

В общем решению взято из исходника https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/, но подходит только для фиксированного по высоте блока position: fixed (если конечно же знаете как выбрать div:target::before то..)

```js
  $(function() {
    var element = $(".top");

    $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(event) {
      element.addClass('intop');
    });

    $(document).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > element.position().top) {
        element.addClass('intop');
      } else {
        element.removeClass('intop');
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
  .intop {
    background: tomato none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  #id3 {
    height: 2500px;
  }
  div:target::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 160px;
    margin-top: -160px;
    width: 1px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#id1">Якорь 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id2">Якорь 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id3">Якорь 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="top">
    <h1>{$offer->name}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{some-link}">Купить</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="{some-link}">Гарантия</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="{some-link}">Доставка</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#id1">Якорь 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id2">Якорь 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id3">Якорь 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id1">Якорь 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id2">Якорь 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id3">Якорь 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id1">Якорь 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id2">Якорь 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id3">Якорь 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id1">Якорь 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id2">Якорь 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#id3">Якорь 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="id1">
    {some-content 1} {some-content}{some-content}{some-content}
  </div>

  <div id="id2">
    {some-content 2} {some-content}{some-content}{some-content}
  </div>

  <div id="id3">
    {some-content 3} {some-content}{some-content}{some-content}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не увидел решения вопроса. При клике на ссылку  "Якорь 3", "div#id3" прячется за div.top. а нужно, что бы он скролился до div.top, а не был с ним на одной высоте.

Comment: хорошо, я понял, сейчас запилю, с таким выдавливанием из вас подробностей у вас будут проблемы с ответами вам))

Comment: @СергейДеревянко добавил

Comment: там похоже но не то. Там изначально есть фиксированный блок, а у меня он динамический. Решил остановить на том, что при фиксации блока, также буду вешать какой нибудь класс на body, и написать соответствующие стили под этот класс..